# Is it possible to use resource IDs instead of their values for xml preferences in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

## The Goal

In my `preferences.xml` I would like to store the ID of certain string elements (like) e.g. ...

```
<string-array name="preference_values">
    <item>@string/nav_start</item>
    <item>@string/nav_overview</item>
    <item>@string/nav_someelse</item>
</string-array>
```

... meanwhile in `xml/pref_general.xml` ...

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="@string/preference_key"
    android:entryValues="@array/preference_values"
    ... />
```

... where the different strings will be localized:

```
<string name="nav_start">Startbildschirm</string>
<string name="nav_overview">Übersicht</string>
<string name="nav_someelse">Sonstige</string>
```

Since I don't want to store the localized strings (as those xml definitions do right now), but rather their integer keys, I would really like to know if there is a way of doing this.

This would make the preferences still available after a language change for example.

## More Background

I really like being able to access/compare resources in code, which are not subjective to typos or name changes (or at least the IDE checks/handles those for you) e.g.:

```
switch( getMyPreferenceAsInt(R.string.preferenece_key) ) {

    case R.string.nav_start:    doSome();     break;
    case R.string.nav_someelse: doSomeElse(); break;
    ...
}
```

I use something similar for my `NavigationDrawer`, and find it really nice to work with. This is also where does string values actually come from (it's like a "default start page" preference).

```
<string-array name="navigation_keys">
    <item>@string/nav_start</item>
    <item>@string/nav_overview</item>
    <item>@string/nav_someelse</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

But at least here I am able to get the keys with `obtainTypedArray(...)`:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mNavKeys = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_keys);
}

void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;
    int selectedResource = mNavKeys.getResourceId(position, R.string.nav_default);

    if (selectedResource == R.string.nav_start) {
        fragment = FancyStartFragment.newinstance();
    }
    else {
        fragment = ...;
    }

    // Fancy methods to do a fragment transaction
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at the article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html . Simply define a default resource, say english strings. After that generate translations.

Comment: @SGrebenkin: Well it is a given to use default resources, and generate the necessary translations. What I am talking about are the cases where you want to have access to a default resource (=key), as well as the users localized version (=displayed text) no matter what language/situation. What you suggest is already what I have implemented in my example here, but I want the stored preferences to be independent of / to survive language changes, etc...

Comment: Right now my tendency is to just define a separate string for each key (`<string name="nav_key_start">nav_start</string>`) as well as what I already have for the localized values (`<string name="nav_start">Startbildschirm</string>`). Which obviously works, but is not as elegant/easy to maintain/rename/...