# Reference the INTEGER value of a string resource in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

Is it possible to reference not the representated string, but the integer key of a resource in xml?

```
<string name="first_string">First! :-D</string>
<string name="second_string">Second :(</string>

<integer-array name="something">
    <item>@string/first_string</item>
    <item>@string/second_string</item>
</integer-array>
```

This for example does not work, because `@string/first_string` is resolved to `First! :-D`, instead of it's resource key (for example `0x7f0c0010`). Is there any way at all to access that?

Comment: Why do you plan to do with this Integer array ?

Comment: @DeepakBala: See following question for (a lot) more details  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603404/ ... in short, I want to compare stored preferences by their R.string.id.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you have integer values in generated R.class of your project.

For instance:

```
int value = R.string.first_string;
```

In XML, it's not possible to get it.

Comment: I know, but this question is about accessing it in the projects **XML** files.

Comment: @Levit, Is it useful ?

Comment: Well, being able to access it like this is a given for the original question. If there was a way to always get the id of a **referenced** resource in code (see my answer), or as stated a way to store the resource key instead of it's value in XML, that would be extremely useful :-/ ... still as it stands your answer has it's right place here as someone searching for a way to simply access it in code might find this very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has a *similar effect* as putting the keys in an xml array, is by accessing it in java with `obtainTypedArray` instead of `getIntArray` or `getStringArray`.

```
typedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.something);
int id = typedArray.getResourceId(0, -1); // 1st param: position, 2nd: default value

if (id == R.string.first_string);  // true
if (id == R.string.second_string); // false
```

Hope that helps someone! For me (op), this seems not to help at all, since I can't access the stored preferences in this way, which is why I needed it in XML directly if at all possible.